# keyboard not working in mac OS x

Tags: windows-8.1, virtual-machine, virtualbox, osx-yosemite

i had recently downloaded mac Os x - Yosemite 10.10.1 on virtual box,the problem is the sign ' @ ' is not appearing whenever i try to enter it. instead the sign' " 'appears through the keyboard. please help me on why i am caused to this problem and a solution will definitely help.i have tried copy and pasting the sign, changing the keyboard settings and various other things bit it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press `alt + l`, this is @ position on a Mac keyboard. (Better than Windows, because you can type it with one hand.) Next time you search for something like this, you should search for keyboard layouts in the Internet. This is not the place for such questions :-)

Comment: I did search though, but thank you very much..!